# Ajax call failing. Using Jquery .ajax function to make simple request

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is the jquery to call the ajax function:

```
   function sendAjax(type, succ){  //where succ is the success callback

   if (type=="")
   {
        $("#txtResp").empty();
        return;
   }

   if(succ === undefined) {   succ = null;  }

   switch(type)
   {
   case 'run':
       $.ajax({type:"GET",
               url: "start_mess.php",
               data: "q="+type,
               success: succ
       }); 
     break;
   }

}
```

Here is the index.html page content:

```
    function initialLoad() 
{                   
    sendAjax('run')
    $("#txtResp").html(responseText);
}

initialLoad();
```

Here is the PHP page:

```
echo $_GET['q'];
$q = $_GET['q'];
```

Any Idea why this is not working? Thank you!

Taylor

Comment: Well, for one thing, you need a semi-colon after `sendAjax('run')`. I also fail to see where `responseText` is defined.

Comment: Are you aware about JS::onReady technique? http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing a callback, so there is nothing to call on success.

Try `sendAjax('run', function(data) { alert(data) });`.

Comment: Simple, clear description. Just what a beginner like me needs. Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry about my response, it's all questions. I didn't have comment permissions yet :p.